# Rails and dirty objects: accessing the values of changed fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I've setup an Event system to display a log of everything that happens to a user. It uses dirty objects.

Here is what I did so far

```
def log_details_change(owner)
  Event.log(owner.condo, :updated_owner_details, [owner.changes.slice('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'start_date', 'phone_number')])
end
```

Now I know that the `owner.changes` method provides a hash that looks like that

```
{ 'title' => ["Title", "New Title"] }
```

If, for instance, I delete the phone number for the user, the hash returned by `owner.changes` becomes

```
{ 'phone_number' => ["514554541", ""] }
```

Basically, the changed value is empty (or blank, or nil - I don't really know).

**How can I access the values in order to check if the changed value is empty?** I'd like to display a string instead of a '' string.

I've tried a lot of different things, including that one below

```
owner.changes.slice('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'start_date', 'phone_number').each_value { |v,k| v.blank? or v.nil? or v.empty? ? 'nope' : v }
```

but it gets me nothing.
Thanks for any help you could give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
owner.changes.map{ |attr, changes| changes[1].blank? ? owner[attribute] = 'nope' : nil }
```

The longer version:

```
owner.changes.map do |attribute, changes|
  changes.map do |old_val, new_val| 
    owner[attribute] = 'was empty' if new_val.blank?
  end
end
```

Tested on my `Intervention` model (attribute `:name`):

```
irb(main):083:0> i = Intervention.first
irb(main):084:0> i.name
=> "création FAV poignet gauche"
irb(main):085:0> i.name = ''
irb(main):086:0> i.changes.map{ |attr, changes| changes.last.blank? ? i[attr] = 'nope' : nil }
=> ["nope"]
irb(main):087:0> i.changes
=> {"name"=>["création FAV poignet gauche", "nope"]}
irb(main):088:0>
```

Comment: The only thing I had to add to make this work was this `owner[attribute][1] = 'was empty' if new_val.blank?`. If I didn't have `[1]`, the code was overriding the table `|old_val,new_val|` with only one val - and I needed the two values (the previous one and the changed one). Thanks so much for your help in this!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, there some dirty one:

Will return values as an array:

```
owner.changes.map{|column_name,column_change| column_change.last.blank? }
=> [true, false]
```

Will return hash with key as changed column and value as true/false for blank:

```
owner.changes.inject({}){|result,col| result[col.first] = col.last.last.blank?; result}
=> {name: true, surname: false}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I took the solution from @MrYoshiji but thanks a lot anyway!